# What's the best way to transform an Array of type Character to a String in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

This question is specifically about converting an Array of type Character to a String.  Converting an Array of Strings or numbers to a string is not the topic of discussion here.

In the following 2 lines, I would expect `myStringFromArray` to be set to "C,a,t!,"

```
    var myChars: [Character] = ["C", "a", "t", "!", ""]
    let myStringFromArray = myChars.joinWithSeparator(",");
```

However, I can't execute that code because the compiler complains about an "ambiguous reference to member `joinWithSeparator`".

So, two questions:

1) Apple says,

> "Every instance of Swift’s Character type represents a single extended
>   grapheme cluster. An extended grapheme cluster is a sequence of one or
>   more Unicode scalars that (when combined) produce a single
>   human-readable character."

Which to me sounds at least homogeneous enough to think it would be reasonable to implement the `joinWithSeparator` method to support the Character type.  So, does anyone have a good answer as to why they don't do that???

**2) What's the best way to transform an Array of type Character to a String in Swift?**

*Note: if you don't want a separator between the characters, the solution would be:*

```
let myStringFromArray = String(myChars)
```

and that would give you "Cat!"

Comment: So far, the answers seem like work (nice) workarounds. What I'm curious about is why the compiler thinks it's ambiguous. Especially if you replace your second line as `joinWithSeparator(Character(","))`

Comment: @TravisGriggs see my updated answer.  It's because the built-in `joinWithSeparator` only supports String types.

Comment: BTW, Swift3 replaces `joinWithSeparator` with `joined(separator:)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Which to me sounds at least homogeneous enough to think it would be reasonable to implement the joinWithSeparator method to support the Character type. So, does anyone have a good answer as to why they don't do that???

This may be an oversight in the design. This error occurs because there are two possible candidates for `joinWithSeparator(_:)`. I suspect this ambiguity exists because of the way Swift can implicit interpret double quotes as either `String` or `Character`. In this context, it's ambiguous as to which to choose.

1. The first candidate is [`joinWithSeparator(_: String) -> String`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_SequenceType_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/intfm/SequenceType/s:FesRxs12SequenceTypeWx9Generator7Element_zSSrS_17joinWithSeparatorFSSSS). It does what you're looking for.

   If the separator is treated as a `String`, this candidate is picked, and the result would be: `"C,a,t,!,"`
2. The second is [`joinWithSeparator<Separator : SequenceType where Separator.Generator.Element == Generator.Element.Generator.Element>(_: Separator) -> JoinSequence<Self>`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_SequenceType_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/intfm/SequenceType/s:FesRxs12SequenceTypeWx9Generator7Element_S_rS_17joinWithSeparatoruRd__S_Wd__S0_S1__zWxS0_S1_S0_S1__rFqd__GVs12JoinSequencex). It's called on a `Sequence` of `Sequence`s, and given a `Sequence` as a seperator. The method signature is a bit of a mouthful, so lets break it down. The argument to this function is of `Separator` type. This `Separator` is constrained to be a `SequenceType` where the elements of the sequence (`Seperator.Generator.Element`) must have the same type as the elements of this sequence of sequences (`Generator.Element.Generator.Element`).

   The point of that complex constraint is to ensure that the `Sequence` remains homogeneous. You can't join sequences of `Int` with sequences of `Double`, for example.

   If the separator is treated as a `Character`, this candidate is picked, the result would be: `["C", ",", "a", ",", "t", ",", "!", ",", ""]`

The compiler throws an error to ensure you're aware that there's an ambiguity. Otherwise, the program might behave differently than you'd expect.

You can disambiguate this situation by this by explicitly making each `Character` into a `String`. Because `String` is **NOT** a `SequenceType`, the #2 candidate is no longer possible.

```
var myChars: [Character] = ["C", "a", "t", "!", ""]
var anotherVar = myChars.map(String.init).joinWithSeparator(",")

print(anotherVar) //C,a,t,!,
```

Comment: `String.init($0)` can be shortened to `String($0)`.

Comment: `.map(String.init)` works as well. I think it's a bit cleaner than `.map { String($0) }`.

Comment: @TimVermeulen fixed.

Answer (score 3):

**This answer assumes Swift 2.2.**

```
var myChars: [Character] = ["C", "a", "t", "!", ""]
var myStrings = myChars.map({String($0)})
var result = myStrings.joinWithSeparator(",")
```

`joinWithSeparator` is only available on String arrays:

```
extension SequenceType where Generator.Element == String {
    /// Interpose the `separator` between elements of `self`, then concatenate
    /// the result.  For example:
    ///
    ///     ["foo", "bar", "baz"].joinWithSeparator("-|-") // "foo-|-bar-|-baz"
    @warn_unused_result
    public func joinWithSeparator(separator: String) -> String
}
```

You could create a new extension to support Characters:

```
extension SequenceType where Generator.Element == Character {

    @warn_unused_result
    public func joinWithSeparator(separator: String) -> String {

        var str = ""

        self.enumerate().forEach({
            str.append($1)

            if let arr = self as? [Character], endIndex: Int = arr.endIndex {
                if $0 < endIndex - 1 {
                    str.append(Character(separator))
                }
            }
        })

        return str
    }
}

var myChars: [Character] = ["C", "a", "t", "!", ""]
let charStr = myChars.joinWithSeparator(",") // "C,a,t,!,"
```

Related discussion on [Code Review.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/133510/73433).

Answer (score 0):

*Context: Swift3(beta)*

**TL;DR Goofy Solution**

```
var myChars:[Character] = ["C", "a", "t", "!", ""]
let separators = repeatElement(Character("-"), count: myChars.count)
let zipped = zip(myChars, separators).lazy.flatMap { [$0, $1] }
let joined = String(zipped.dropLast())
```

**Exposition**

OK. This drove me nuts. In part because I got caught up in the `join` semantics. A join method is very useful, but when you back away from it's very specific (yet common) case of string concatenation, it's doing two things at once. It's splicing other elements in with the original sequence, and then it's flattening the 2 deep array of characters (array of strings) into one single array (string).

The OPs use of single characters in an Array sent my brain elsewhere. The answers given above are the simplest way to get what was desired. Convert the single characters to single character strings and then use the join method.

If you want to consider the two pieces separately though... We start with the original input:

```
var input:[Character] = ["C", "a", "t", "!", ""]
```

Before we can splice our characters with separators, we need a collection of separators. In this case, we want a pseudo collection that is the same thing repeated again and again, without having to actually make any array with that many elements:

```
let separators = repeatElement(Character(","), count: myChars.count)
```

This returns a `Repeated` object (which oddly enough you cannot instantiate with a regular `init` method).

Now we want to splice/weave the original input with the separators:

```
let zipped = zip(myChars, separators).lazy.flatMap { [$0, $1] }
```

The `zip` function returns a `Zip2Sequence`(also curiously must be instantiated via free function rather than direct object reference). By itself, when enumerated the Zip2Sequence just enumerates paired tuples of `(eachSequence1, eachSequence2)`. The `flatMap` expression turns that into a single series of alternating elements from the two sequences.

For large inputs, this would create a largish intermediary sequence, just to be soon thrown away. So we insert the `lazy` accessor in there which lets the transform only be computed on demand as we're accessing elements from it (think iterator).

Finally, we know we can make a String from just about any sort of Character sequence. So we just pass this directly to the String creation. We add a dropLast() to avoid the last comma being added.

```
let joined = String(zipped.dropLast())
```

The valuable thing about decomposing it this way (it's definitely more lines of code, so there had better be a redeeming value), is that we gain insight into a number of tools we could use to solve problems similar, but not identical, to `join`. For example, say we want the trailing comma? Joined isn't the answer. Suppose we want a non constant separator? Just rework the 2nd line. Etc...